# prevent image hotlinking but allow direct access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use Amazon S3 to store my website's images. I have a bucket policy that stops other websites hotlinking my images.

To get this to work, I have the file permission set to "private" in S3 and then the bucket policy opens access up to my website only.

This works fine, but because the file is "private" I cannot view the image directly in a browser, and this is something I want to allow.

Here is the policy

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "preventHotLinking",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "http://mydomain.com/*",
            "http://www.mydomain.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, to summarise:

- the file itself is set to private
- the above policy allows images to be displayed on pages from the domain "mydomain.com" but not on "someoneelsesdomain.com"

This also blocks direct access though, so pasting http://jbtestyt.s3.amazonaws.com/archie.jpg into a browser does not show the image (because it is private).

But I would like the image to display for direct access.

Possibly the solution is to make the file public then deny all referrers apart from ones I list? But I was not sure, and could not find anything like that.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am inferring that you are looking for a "native" S3 solution, so here goes. If you really think about it, hotlinking in essence is "directly accessing" the file. Therefore, "the file itself is set to private" will always ensure that (on AWS at least) you cannot directly access it no matter what. This is by design on S3. What you suggest for whitelisting referrers is probably the only straightforward way that you're going to accomplish this using S3 alone.